# Horizontal <ul> navigation - how to vertical align contents of <li>

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have a horizontal `<ul>` styled with CSS. Works nice, rolloevers everything, however, the list has a height of 50px and I need to position the in the links in the vertical middle. For some reason, I can't figure out how to do that...

The relevant code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/XPFMB/

How to make the "ssss" links go to the middle of the grey bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `line-height: 50px;` to your CSS for `.nav ul li a`

Answer (score 1):

Add line-height to the `li`'s CSS:

```
.nav li {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F6nFU/1/).

This *will* cause problems if your text is long enough to run to a second line, though; however to account for that you *could* use `min-width` (instead of `width`) on the `a` elements, and then add `white-space: nowrap` to both the `ul` *and* the `li`:

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav li {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XPFMB/2/).

It's still not perfect; but it does reduce the likelihood of the layout breaking by using link-text a few characters too long.

Comment: thanx david :) it's a nav bar so actually i can make the items fixed width as it won't change... i'll upvote your answer and give the correct to the first response cause you were both right (he just was a bit faster lol)

Comment: No problem; glad to have been of help! =)